# SQL Server: Persisting computed column

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

I have some order related tables. Order, OrderLines, OrderWarehouse etc.

The Orders table contains some computed columns (TotalNetPrice, TotalVATPrice etc).

I need them to be persisted columns as I need to include them in some indexes.

My question:

The columns themselves call functions which take the order tables Id field and return the calculated value.

Is there a way of forcing the values to be recalculated when ANY of the Order related tables change (as they all effect the calculations)?

Edit: (...without writing triggers)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about persisting the computed column while allowing it to recalculate whenever one of the variables are changed, however I would almost approach this one using a View. when you select from the view it almost acts like a table and it could have your computed columns updated on the fly, however when you need to save new data you would save it to the originating column rather than the view.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't an option in the software that implements the database. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Which software are you using to implement?

Comment: Ah, I've never tried that. Sorry I can't help you further. Good luck